# Icon not showing in web push notification Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, web-push, angular-service-worker

I am working on web push notification using Angular and NodeJs. In Nodejs i'm using web-push npm package and Angular using SwPush class from service worker. Everything seems working fine except while receiving push notification from back end notification icon not showing.

Receiving notification using swpush:

```
swPush.messages.subscribe(
      (notification: any) => {
        console.log("received push message", notification);

        let options = {
          body: notification.body,
          icon: "http://localhost:3000/assets/img/logo.png",
          badge: "http://localhost:3000/assets/img/logo.png",
          image:"http://localhost:3000/assets/img/logo.png",
          actions: <any>notification.actions,
          data: notification.data,
          vibrate: [100, 50, 10, 20, 20],
        };
        this.showNotificationss(notification.title, options)
      },

      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
```

Notification function which is used to show the notification:

```
  showNotificationss(title: string, options: NotificationOptions) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(reg => {
      reg.showNotification(title, options).then(res => {
        console.log("showed notification", res)
      }, err => {
        console.error(err)
      });
    });
    }
```

NodeJs router to sent the notification to client:

```
app.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
  const subscription = req.body;
  res.status(201).json({});
  const payload = JSON.stringify({ title: 'test',  icon: "http://localhost:3000/assets/img/logo.png",
          badge: "http://localhost:3000/assets/img/logo.png", });
  webpush.sendNotification(subscription, payload).catch(error => {
    console.error(error.stack);
  });
});
```

This is the notification which is now i'm getting. It will always showing chrome icon instead of icon which i was mentioning.

[image]

I tried everything but notification icon not changed always showing chrome icon. How can i fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use https link for images

Comment: Actually i want to show the logo which i pushed instead of chrome logo. I tried but no luck

Comment: ok try to upload it on a public ip (or cdn) and in https

Comment: @dhamodharan Please post an answer if you had any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Icon URL is available only in secure contexts(HTTPS)